# Python, function calls within same class for GUI

Tags: python, function, class, user-interface

Hello i am trying to make a simple GUI, i have a button which calls a function to import some excel data, i would then like to process those data in another function within the same class. Below is my code for the two functions, rhe first one imports the data, then i would like to use the data from OpendirREF in the function Confidens. Can anyone help?

```
def OpendirREF(self):
    filePath_REF = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', '*.xlsx')) #  \n *.txt')

    fileHandle_REF = os.path.basename(filePath_REF)

    data_REF = pd.read_excel(fileHandle_REF)

    return data_REF

def Confidens(self):

    imported_data = self.OpendirREF()
    print imported_data
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: My problem is that i would like to print or access the data data_REF from function OpendirREF down in the function Confidens eg. print it or do other calculations with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your asking how to call the function in same class .if so

If you want to refer to it, something like this

> classname.OpendirREF(self).

Comment: Hmm not entirely what i want, because now i get the pop-up file-dialog (str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', '*.xlsx'))) again from the OpendirREF function before it prints the data. i would like to only access the output of the OpendirREF function.

Comment: So you want data_REF? Just try to assign to variable

Comment: But how? i need the syntax. I guess data_REF needs to be global if i need to use it in other functions

Comment: Okay found out, how to do it by using global variable